# Trying to hit port

Tags: back4app

So I'm trying to create a python discord bot on back4app containers, and I have the dockerfile. When I first made my app it said the dockerfile needed to expose top port so I exposed port 443 cause thats what discord uses I think.

Now it says

```
2023-03-02T09:41:35.105Z # trying to hit the 443 port using http.
2023-03-02T09:41:35.108Z # it looks that no process is listening to the 443 port using http
(and then it just keeps retrying until it gives up)
2023-03-02T09:41:35.109Z # app did not turn healthy after several checks
2023-03-02T09:41:35.110Z # deployment failed
```

Although the bot still runs fine as long as its still deploying. I guessed I need some kind of website or something to occupy a port but idrk. Help?